# Select similar IP addresses - ignore last 3 digits

Tags: mysql

I have a table with usernames and IPs.
I need to get a list of the users who have similar IP -*ignore last 3 or 2 or 1 digit(s)*-

Example: 
Count **190.200.210.180** and **190.200.210.60** as the same IP.
Count **205.50.4.30** and **205.50.4.197** as the same IP.

The field type of IPs is set as varchar and this is something I cannot change at the moment.

Currently I'm using :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( username ) names, IPs, COUNT( IPs ) AS Instances 
FROM users
GROUP BY IPs
HAVING (COUNT(IPs) >1)
ORDER BY  `Instances ` DESC
```

to get the users with the same IP.
[image: SQL statement output]

Is it possible with the field of the IPs being set as varchar to make a select statement to group users with similar ips?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(username) AS names, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(IPs, '.', 3) AS IPs
    COUNT(*) AS Instances 
FROM
    users
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(IPs, '.', 3)
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    Instances DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

The function SUBSTR_INDEX makes parsing an IP address an easy operation:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(y.IPs,'.',1),'.',-1) a,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(y.IPs,'.',2),'.',-1) b,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(y.IPs,'.',3),'.',-1) c,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(y.IPs,'.',4),'.',-1) d
  FROM (SELECT ... FROM users) y
```

Using the aliased octets a,b,c,d as a base, you should be able to apply similar logic to your question and perform the octet-matching you desire...

Comment: Very cool.  Just curious, why did you use a sub-select in your from clause?

Comment: The user could probably just group by a, b and c with what you have above.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would go about eliminating the last ***.nnn*** part as in…

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`username` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'names',
    SUBSTRING(`IPs`,1,(CHAR_LENGTH(`IPs`)-CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`IPs`,'.',-1))-1)) AS 'roughIP',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Instances'
FROM `users`
GROUP BY `roughIP`
ORDER BY `Instances` DESC
```

Comment: Nice alternative. The only thing is that it uses more resources, because of the use of SUBSTRING 2 times and CHAR_LENGTH function also.

Comment: You're right but I wouldn't be sure that each IP will have *n* amount of periods.